# Edit History For A Channel Entry?

Tags: database

Is there a way to see what the edit history is of channel entry? I'm happy to look into the database, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [user guide](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/publish.html#revisions-tab), if you have Entry Versioning enabled in Admin ‣ Channel Administration ‣ Channels, a Revisions tab will appear on the entry publish/edit screen allowing you to see all of the revisions for the entry.

Comment: Note - if you turn this on retrospectively (after entries have been created), it won't change the existing entries, only new entries. So you'll have to go into each entry turning it on (in the publish/Edit screen a tick box will appear in the revisions tab to turn it on for previous entries).